# Seattle to Minneapolis - Cheapest flight option for the next 2 days?

Tags: air-travel, usa, budget, seattle, minneapolis

So i need to travel this week to a state and return flight ticket is $800+. I obviously don't want to pay this much. Is there a way or "hack" by which i can get flight tickets for cheap?

Flying from Seattle to Minneapolis, tomorrow or Friday. And I'm a student (if that could help bring the price down?).

Comment: If you rephrase the question as *on short notice* or so, it might survive and not be closed as *too localised*.

Comment: I think this really too localized and should be a theme for discussion on chat.

Answer (score 2):

[Amtrak tickets are sold starting at at $328](http://tickets.amtrak.com/itd/amtrak), and you'll get a nice experience too.

[Greyhound tickets are sold at $188.10](https://www.greyhound.com/farefinder/step2.aspx).

Flying is rarely the cheapest option if you don't have the option to book a long time in advance and to be flexible in the dates.